# Get Sum of average in SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

In my cube I have a model like below:

[image]

When I remove [Claims Ref No] column it changes as below:

[image]

[Total Paid] column value is correct here.

But I want to keep [Total Premium To Policy Holder] column as 1433.25 for [Policy Ref No] HTEST9545.. instead of 2866.5 (1433.25 + 1433.25)

Similarly if I remove the column [Policy Ref No] I want the value 1779.06 (1433.25 + 345.81) as the [Total Premium To Policy Holder] value instead of 3212.31 (1433.25 + 1433.25 + 345.81)

[image]

So my requirement is like I want to eliminate duplicates of premiums based on [Policy Ref No] when sum up.
Or in other words group the premium values by [Policy Ref No] and then take the sum.

Any help to solve this matter is appreciated.

Comment: When you remove [Claims Ref No], do you want the first value of [Total Premium To Policy Holder] measure? Imagine you have not equal values of [Total Premium To Policy Holder] for different [Claims Ref No] within same [Policy Ref No] - which value do you want to get?

Comment: That cannot happen. Because this is one to many relationship. One policy can have many claims. I want Claim Cost total for Policy Premium.

Comment: can you change the aggregation type specified for the measure to Max?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you will need a SCOPE on the measure [Total Premium To Policy Holder] in order to override the default aggregation.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider making an [edit] to your answer to show the questioner more details about what to do.